# C# - Hiding WinForm With Opacity 0 Not working on Win 7

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a win form that is inserted into another application using some Win32 magic via a .dll call .

I have to use custom control on the minimize and maximize events on the winform, because the default min/max operations break the panel's housing inside the parent window.

To get around this problem, I use opacity 0 just to make the panel invisible/visible on min/max operations. I use a custom button inside the host program for the maximize panel operation.

I am capturing the windows msgs to hook into this functionality.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {


        const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        const int SC_MAXIMIZE   = 0xF030;
        const int SC_MINIMIZE   = 0xF020;
        const int WM_CLOSE      = 0x0010;

        //user clicked close
        if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE)
        {
            //custom code for close event
        }
        if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            switch ((int)m.WParam)
            {
                case SC_MAXIMIZE:
                    //disable maximize button
                    return;

                case SC_MINIMIZE:

                    //hide the form by making it invisible, then disabling it
                    //this prevents form being detached from parent chart
                    HidePanel();
                    return;                        
            }
        }
        //return control back to windows
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

So when HidePanel is called...

```
    //panel delegate
    private delegate void TradePanelDelegate();

    private void _HidePanel()
    {
        Opacity = 0;            
        Enabled = false;
        _formMinimzed = true;
    }

    private void HidePanel()
    {
        try
        {
            TradePanelForm thisForm = this;
            thisForm.Invoke(new TradePanelDelegate(_HidePanel));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

This works perfectly fine on Windows 10. But tests on windows 7 cause an exception, which seems to be centered around the opacity trick.

Here is the exception thrown on windows 7 when HidePanel() is called...

[image: Exception when HidePanel is called]

I am also using a delegate to call the 'UI Thread' to make the changes, as an attempt to fix this issue. It didn't make a difference.

Any suggestions? I am only an intermediate level C# programmer at this stage.